# Efficient way to calculate average MAPE and MSE in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I have a real data and predicted data and I want to calculate overall MAPE and MSE. The data are time series, with each column representing data for different weeks. I predict value for each of the 52 weeks for each of the items as shown below. What would be the best possible calculate overall Error in R.

```
real = matrix( 
    c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", .5, .7, 0.40, 0.6, 0.3, 0.29, 0.7, 0.09, 0.42, 0.032, 0.3, 0.37), 
     nrow=4, 
     ncol=4) 
colnames(real) <- c("item", "week1", "week2", "week3")


predicted = matrix( 
  c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", .55, .67, 0.40, 0.69, 0.13, 0.9, 0.47, 0.19, 0.22, 0.033, 0.4, 0.37), 
  nrow=4, 
  ncol=4) 
colnames(predicted) <- c("item", "week1", "week2", "week3")
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the predicted values in the first place? The model you use to get the predicted values is probably based on minimising some function of prediction errors (usually MSE). Therefore, if you calculate your predicted values, the residuals and some metrics on MSE and MAPE have been calculated somewhere along the line in fitting the model. You can probably retrieve them directly.

If the predicted values happened to be thrown into your lap and you have nothing to do with fitting the model, then you calculate MSE and MAPE as per below:

You have only one record per week for every item. So for every item, you can only calculate one *prediction error* per week. Depending on your application, you can choose to calculate the MSE and MAPE per item or per week.

This is what your data looks like:

```
real <- matrix( 
  c(.5, .7, 0.40, 0.6, 0.3, 0.29, 0.7, 0.09, 0.42, 0.032, 0.3, 0.37), 
  nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
colnames(real) <- c("week1", "week2", "week3")

predicted <- matrix( 
  c(.55, .67, 0.40, 0.69, 0.13, 0.9, 0.47, 0.19, 0.22, 0.033, 0.4, 0.37), 
  nrow = 4, ncol = 3) 
colnames(predicted) <- c("week1", "week2", "week3")
```

Calculate the (percentage/squared) errors for every entry:

```
pred_error    <- real - predicted 
pct_error     <- pred_error/real
squared_error <- pred_error^2
```

Calculate MSE, MAPE:

```
# For per-item prediction errors
apply(squared_error,  MARGIN = 1, mean)    # MSE
apply(abs(pct_error), MARGIN = 1, mean)    # MAPE

# For per-week prediction errors
apply(squared_error,  MARGIN = 0, mean)    # MSE
apply(abs(pct_error), MARGIN = 0, mean)    # MAPE
```